# Localize image in windows phone 7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, localization, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone application. Here we use localization in our app. We currently supporting 2 languages in our app. Texts are changed to the selected language by using resource files. But I need to change some images that showing in my app based on the language. Now I am doing it by checking the phone culture pragmatically and change the image path. Is it possible to localize image files too as the same way we localize the strings ?. If it possible how can I do that? .

I googled it, but didn't got any information about localizing images in an application in windows phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the uri for your image to a resource file just like you do with strings (different uri in different resource file for different language) and use it with binding.